# Switch to *grep* buffer after running rgrep

Tags: rgrep

I have assigned C-c C-g to rgrep, this works fine, however I am still in the buffer I was in and not in the *grep* buffer which loads the results.

After hitting C-c C-g and running rgrep, I want to be in the *grep* buffer how do I do this?

I tried writing a new function

```el
(defun rgrep-switch() 
   (interactive)
   (rgrep)
   (switch-to-buffer "*grep*"))
```

but this is throwing an error.

Comment: Have you tried just hitting M-g n?  Or C-x <backtick>?  This brings you to the first grep result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're calling `rgrep` with no arguments. In this case you clearly want to obtain the arguments interactively, so you can use `call-interactively` to do that.

It also sounds like you wanted to select the window with the grep results, rather than switch to the grep results in the current window?

```el
(defun rgrep-switch() 
  "Call `rgrep' and select its window."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'rgrep)
  (select-window (get-buffer-window "*grep*")))
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between select-window and switch-to-buffer?

Comment: Use `C-h f` to ask Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it that's a little cleaner.

```
(add-hook 'grep-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*grep*")))
```

Let me explain what's going on here.

The problem has two parts. We want to (1) call a function which switches us to the `*grep*` buffer (2) after `grep-mode` has loaded.

Regarding the part (2), this is precisely what "mode hooks" are for.  A "mode hook" is a variable which contains code to be run after a mode has loaded.  In situations like these, always check for a hook!<sup>1</sup>  It turns out that `grep-mode` has the `grep-mode-hook`.  When the `grep` command is run, it creates a buffer which uses `grep-mode`.  Therefore, we can use the `grep-mode-hook` to run our switching function.

Now, we could create an explicit function for part (1), like in [phil's response](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24579/15177), but it's unlikely we'll ever use it elsewhere.  Instead, let's create an "anonymous function" using `lambda`.  With `lambda`, a function is created temporarily and, once it has been used, is discarded.  This keeps our Emacs instance a little cleaner.

You can read more about each function/variable by using `C-h f` or `C-h v`, respectively.

---

<sup>1</sup> One way to search would be to do `C-h v` and then type in `grep <SPC> hook <SPC> <SPC>`.  This will show `grep-mode-hook` and `grep-setup-hook` as potential options.  You can then look at the documentation for each of them to see which is more appropriate.